# How to make the display NOT scaled when playing game?

Tags: display, intel-graphics, scaling

My game resolution is different from my laptop display one and that makes the game scaled ugly when played.

I google around and people say I should turn off auto-scaling feature of the mornitor.

My question is how can I do that. To what I would find on my PC is as in the snapshot though I cannnot turn it off at the checkbox.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: The option you want might be hidden if 1920 x 1080 is the display's native resolution. See if you get different options for a lower resoltion that you want to play in.

Comment: I'll try and let you know if it works. Thank you

Comment: Yeah switching to another resolution gives me more scaling options. Please post your comment as an answer to get accepted @Louis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try choosing a lower resolution to see if more scaling options become available.

The full set of options for scaling could be hidden if the resolution setting matches that of the display's native one, as their effects may not be meaningful in that context.